# Android get all assets folder images

Tags: android, directory, assets

How to retrive all images from folder named 'imagesf' in assets folder and using it as int[] instead of

```
int[] mImages = new int[]{
 R.drawable.pic1
,R.drawable.pic2
,R.drawable.pic3
,R.drawable.pic4
};
```

To use it in a viewpager

Comment: That is not possible. And your view pager can do without.

Comment: @greenapps it is possible by reflecting the `R.drawable` class and getting the values of all the fields. It's just not worth the effort and time.

Comment: Please can u give me an example or give me example for R.drawable class code

Comment: This website is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code to get all image name from 'imagesf' in assets folder

```
private List<String> getImage(Context context) throws IOException {
  AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
  String[] files = assetManager.list("imagesf");   
  List<String> it = Arrays.asList(files);
  return it; 
}
```

and get one by one image as Bitmap by using below code iterating in loop:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: But it give me the images as a String but i want as int[] to use it in viewpager

Comment: int[] is not possible. becuase you are in assets folder.